# Return type of generic method

Tags: .net, generics, methods, return-type

I have a generic method which is to return an object of the generic type. Some code:

```
public static T Foo<T>(string value)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
        return value;

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        return Int32.Parse(value);

    // Do more stuff
}
```

I can see that the compiler might complain about this (*"Cannot convert type 'String' to 'T'"*), even if the code shouldn't cause any logical errors runtime. Is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for? Casting doesn't help...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, you *can* do this:

```
public static T Foo<T>(string value)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
        return (T) (object) value;

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        return (T) (object) Int32.Parse(value);

    ...
}
```

That will involve boxing for value types, but it will work.

Are you sure this is best done as a single method though, rather than (say) a generic interface which can be implemented by different converters?

Alternatively, you might want a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` like this:

```
Dictionary<Type, Delegate> converters = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>
{
    { typeof(string), new Func<string, string>(x => x) }
    { typeof(int), new Func<string, int>(x => int.Parse(x)) },
}
```

then you'd use it like this:

```
public static T Foo<T>(string value)
{
    Delegate converter;
    if (converters.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out converter))
    {
        // We know the delegate will really be of the right type
        var strongConverter = (Func<string, T>) converter;
        return strongConverter(value);
    }
    // Oops... no such converter. Throw exception or whatever
}
```

Comment: I had to do return (T)(object)value; for String as well, but that works. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Chris: The dictionary approach feels a little cleaner to me... and would avoid boxing for value types.

Comment: @Jon: The read method in question is a bit more complex than what I wrote here - I just highlighted the problem I had. So your alternative approach doesn't really relate, but I agree - that would be a cleaner approach to this kind of method.

Comment: @Jon: Just noticed you added (string) to the return statement for string. This doesn't work - it seems it must be (object), FYI.

Comment: I did a little benchmark... I think the compiler ignores the (T)(object) conversion (the times are the same if I call the "generic" function or if I call a more function that calls directly Int32.Parse)